# How to get licenese URL from Azure Media Service DRM

Tags: .net, azure, video.js, azure-media-services, drm

I am using `Azure Media Services v3` to create a VoD player application, and I am using the built-in DRM support (Widevine, PlayReady, FairPlay) to encrypt the data. My solution uses `Video.js` player on the client side with the `videojs-contrib-eme` package to play the content.

My problem is that for the DRM configuration I have to provide a license URL for the player, but I have not found any API to get the license URL.

The only solution I found is getting the url from the DASH manifest, and then replace parts of the URL with the correct DRM typename, like described here: [Github repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-3rdparty-player-samples/tree/master/setup#setup-vodps1) in section 9 of the `setup-vod.ps1` description. It seems like a sketchy workaround and I am courious if there is any documentation or API to do this correctly. Does anyone have any tutorial, example, or docs for a correct solution or I am already using the best one with the linked solution?

Answer (score 1):

For production systems, customers usually have a CMS storing LA_URLs and players can rely on CMS for these info.

For cases without such CMS, you have to parse DASH MPD for PlayReady and Widevine LA_URLs and HLS playlist for FairPlay LA_URL.

This test player does exactly this (dropdown to DRM at the bottom of the diagnostic overlay): https://openidconnectweb.azurewebsites.net/AMTestPlayer?url=https://eventgridmediaservice-usw22.streaming.media.azure.net/2fa069bd-2b0c-4674-bff7-26ebd6cdc224/MicrosoftElite01.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf,encryption=cenc)

Comment: What do you mean by CMS? Content Management System? We have a backend system to store the URL-s. My problem is that how can I get them in the first place to store them.

Comment: Once you have a media service account in Azure, the license URL host name is fixed. You can then use the URL format with each content key ID to construct the full URL and store in CMS (Content Management Service).